# Application is throwing errors when explored through Selenium automation

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

We have developed applications in ASP.NET MVC, JS/JQuery, Redis cache. We do an automation round of testing using selenium(coded in c#.net).

The application works well when explored manually.

But through automation scripts, we observe issues like data not loaded completely or requested JS files are not loaded.

We introduced 2 seconds wait as well in the scripts, but no luck.

Comment: What kind of errors do you get?

Comment: Update the question with your code trials and relevant error stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please provide your code and the website you're working with. There's not enough information to check what the problem is.